# Running batch script on a server, with windows OS

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler, anaconda3

I have a server which is running 24/7 and I wanted to know how I can create a script that will run my code in an anconda enviornment

I tried using the following code on Windows Task Scheduler, didnt work

```
call "C:\Users\c.batth\anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat" ArcGIS & cd "C:\Users\c.batth\anaconda3\envs\ArcGIS\Scripts" & python ExtractChanges.py
```